# Descargar archivos desde un servidor a un cliente

Tags: java, ftp, servidor

no logro poder descargar el archivo y porsupuesto la linea erronea esta en la parte del FileInputStream, no logro que el cliente reciba el archivo que el desea, alguna sugerencia para poder descargar un archivo de un servidor a un cliente? sin librerias apache.

```
public void rename (String filename){
        File f = new File(path + filename);
        try{
            if(f.exists()){
                System.out.println("Whats the new name?");
                String newname = input.nextLine();
                File newFile = new File(path + newname);
                f.renameTo(newFile);
                System.out.println(">>Rename has been done");
                }
            else
                System.out.println(">>The rename couldnt complete");    }//try
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
    }//rename

    public void download (String filename){
        File f = new File(path + filename);
        try{if(f.exists()){
         System.out.println("");
         System.out.println("Starting");
         System.out.println(">>Receiving file: "+ filename + "  " );
         System.out.println(">>Please wait...");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(f);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(f);
         byte[] b=new byte[1024];
         while((fileInputStream.read(b))>0)fileOutputStream.write(b);
         fileOutputStream.flush();
         fileOutputStream.close();
         fileInputStream.close();
              System.out.println(">>Task completed!");  }//if
        else{
            System.out.println(">>File not found"); }
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

y esta es la clase servidor

```
public class Server {
public static final int PORT = 9000;
static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
static Commands opeFiles = new Commands();
static int max = 10; // Maximo de conexiones simultaneas

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket ss = null; 
        Socket s = null;
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(PORT, max);
        System.out.println("- -Kush Server - -");
        while(true){
            s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
            System.out.println("SERVER WORKING ON ADDRESS -> " + s.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "/" + PORT);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String msg = (String)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("From Client >> " + msg);
            System.out.println("C:>" + msg);
            String[] cmds = msg.split(" ");
            File f = new File(cmds[1]);
            switch(cmds[0]){
            case "create":  
                opeFiles.create(cmds[1]);
                oos.writeObject("File Created");
                break;
            case "read":
                String content = opeFiles.read(cmds[1]);
                if(f.exists()){
                oos.writeObject(content);
                }
                else{
                    oos.writeObject("File not found");
                }
                break;
            case "delete":
                opeFiles.delete(cmds[1]);
                try{
                    if(f.exists()){    
                    oos.writeObject("File Deleted");
                    }
                    else{
                        oos.writeObject("File not found");
                    }   
                }//try
                catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
                break;
            case "rename":
                opeFiles.rename(cmds[1]);
                break;
            case "download":
                opeFiles.download(cmds[1]);
                oos.writeObject(f);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Undefined Operation");
                oos.writeObject("Undefined Operation");
                break;
            }//case
        }//while
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            s.close();
            ss.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
}
```

}
}

Comment: veo que en la etiqueta pones FTP ¿tu intención es hacer tu propia implementación del protocolo FTP? o ¿solamente quieres pasar un archivo de un servidor a un cliente?